# failed to connect to a database in B1if

Tags: sapb1

sometimes i have this error when i try to connect to my database in B1if :

```
vBIU.errhdlg='' exceptionmsg='com.sap.b1i.xcellerator.XcelleratorException: XCE001 Nested exception:
com.sap.b1i.bizprocessor.BizProcException: BPE001 Nested exception:
com.sap.b1i.xcellerator.XcelleratorException: XCE001 Nested exception:
com.sap.b1i.xcellerator.XcelleratorException: XCE001 Nested exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Connect to
Business One failed. (-119) Database server type not supported -b1Server=SRV-B1-HYPPROD,
company=SBO_HYPFR_PROD, licenseServer=HYP-B1-LIC:30000, dbType=7, dbUser=sa, userName=B1i-' msglogexcl='false'
handover2CentralSrv='' MessageLog='true' msglogdbop='insert'>
```

the question is how to fix that ?

Comment: why dont you add your code to the question, that gives this exception? from the exception message, it seems like you have specified the dbtype as 7 and it is not supported "Database server type not supported"

Comment: Show some code and give more contextal information if you want to receive an answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

The Error happens when B1i don't get a connection to the DB. That should not be a problem because B1i repeats the process after a minuten and then the connection should be there.

Answer (score 0):

We fixed this by Installing the 64 Bit version of B1DIAPI.x64. Not sure why that worked. 
Note you need to update the SLD links for your database and SBO-COMMON - the jcoPath will likely be different - replace the "Program Files (x86)" with just "Program Files".